# What is happening to the integer when there is leading zero?

Tags: java

```
int num = 000111;
System.out.println(num);
```

The output is 73.

Why is this happening?

How can I make the output to be 111? Or, How can I make the value to become 111.

Answer (score 9):

A leading 0 means the value is expressed in octal notation. To make it 111 dont use leading zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

The leading zero causes the integer literal to be interpreted as octal value. 111<sub>oct</sub> = 73<sub>dec</sub>

You should remove the leading zeros.